Operation not permitted when creating .nomedia file on /storage/emulated/0/Pictures
I don't have root access, Android 14: with terminal shell
touch /storage/emulated/0/Pictures/.nomedia
cannot touch '.nomedia': operation not permitted

I can't create any files, but I can create folders
echo -n touch /storage/emulated/0/Pictures/.nomedia
bash: .nomedia: operation not permitted

no matter if the file is empty or not.
